# responsive layers with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i have 3 images. One per layer. Each picture must change its size and still be positioned with relative to each other. First layer is like i bg for second, and third is just glare fore bg and second layer. I try some kind, but my second layer width does not match to the parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
 <img src="_/pic/bg.jpg" alt="" class="bg"/>
 <div class="cont">
   <img /> or some text
 </div>
 <img src="_/pic/shine.png" alt="" class="fr"/>
</div>
```

sorry for bad English
should look like this http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y155/R_E_D/example.jpg

also i use

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
```

feel free to change html and css

Comment: Rather than using images, if these are supposed to be background images, use them as background-images! These could be applied to `div` styles

Comment: background-size: 100%; not good variant =(

Comment: can you post a visual exapmle of what are you trying to achieve? i mean the actual final effect of layered images. Maybe we can replace at least "shine" with CSS3 solution.

Comment: yes http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y155/R_E_D/example.jpg

Comment: In order to match the second layer (`div.cont`) to the first (`div.parent`) you can use `.parent{position:relative;} .parent .cont {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; left:0; bottom:0;}`. But it's hard to tell without your CSS definitions.

Comment: did not help, when the window is narrow everything is all right, but when the window becomes wider ... problems begin [upd] i think add max-width in px maybe help with this problem

Answer (score 0):

your second layer doesn't match up because it doesn't have the same relationship as the other two layers with the `parent` div. The second layer is inside of a div.

Moreover, unlike `img`'s, `div`'s are dimensionless by default. You have to set the width on those too to have it be resizeable to match the parent div like the other two layers.

Given your HTML above, try this CSS:

```
img, .cont {max-width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to place the layers in a fluid-container, and make the container responsive, create a container if you already don't have one

```
.container {

  position: relative; /* Important */
  width: 200; /* Any width */
  height: 200; /* Any height */
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;

  }
```

after that add each layer in a class inside the container and make sure you use the absolute position in each layer..
adjust the layout for responsiveness and let the container use do the magic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).